# How to click a button with event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

There is a website called *https://freesound.org* and I would like to press the play button with JavaScript.

I tried

`document.getElementsByClassName("play toggle")[0].click();`

and it works only if you have already clicked anywhere in the page. I also tried `focus()` on an element in the page but it will not work. Do I need to do this with an input event? How I could?

Comment: It's working for me (Chrome/Mac). In which browser/OS are you not able to do that?

Comment: I am using Firefox Portable. I didn't know that work for Chrome. Windows 10

Comment: @sebasaenz Is it possible to work for Firefox?

Comment: There is no way for this to work in Firefox. Firefox have their own policy to block autoplay and the user has to allow permissions in Firefox to autoplay audio/video. As show in the screenshot: https://ibb.co/mNRP3yL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Media [autoplay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide) behavior is browser dependent. For instance, Chrome [does not allow](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) audio autoplay until the user has interacted with the page (click, tap, etc).

If you are only worried about autoplay in your browser, Chrome [has a flag](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/02/06/how-to-control-audio-and-video-autoplay-in-google-chrome/) that you can set to allow audio to play without user interaction. If you are trying to create a script/extension/etc that will impact other users, you will need to research the behavior of the browser(s) you are targeting.

**Edit:** just saw that you are using Firefox Portable. Information about autoplay behavior can be found [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/block-autoplay).

Comment: Cool, thank you. I didn't know about the flag. Can this flag be changed by code?

Comment: Not from a JavaScript environment running on the page. There are [command line options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options) available if you are launching the browser from an application. I am unsure if Extensions have the ability to change flags.